# Jetpack Compose - How to search and display specific data from room in LazyColumn?

Tags: android-room, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I want to fetch data from room table using a search query and present the result in LazyColumn instead of the someList I present there.

In other words, how to implement search function using compose from room table?

```
//Getting the list from room and presenting it in lazy column

val someList by mainViewModel.getSomeItems.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())


LazyColumn(
 verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
  modifier = Modifier
   .fillMaxSize()
    .padding(16.dp)
                        ) {
                            
itemsIndexed(items = someList) { itemIndex, item ->


//not really important to the question
item.currentInventory?.let {

MainScreenItemRow(
itemId = item.id,
itemNumber = item.itemNumber,
itemDescription = item.itemDescription,
currentInventory = it,
)
             }
         }
     }
} // end of lazy
```

I want to use DAO query and present the result list if query matches to one of the items in "someList".

```
@Query("SELECT * from someList WHERE id LIKE :search OR itemNumber LIKE :search OR itemDescription LIKE :search")
    fun searchInventory (search: String): Flow<List<SomeList>>
```

How can I insert the query results into a list and present it in lazy column?

Comment: Hi, please format your code so that it's more readable so that people can help you faster :)

Comment: @ Stelios Papamichail
Tried to simplify the question. Let me know if it makes more sense, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving my updated code for people who might need it. Didn't use DAO or anything like that, just filtering the main list with some adjustments:

SearchView:

```
@Composable
fun SearchView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: MutableState<TextFieldValue>,
    placeHolder: String
    ) {

    TextField(
        value = state.value,
        onValueChange = { value ->
            state.value = value
        )

}
```

Main Screen that presents final list

```
val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

//Place the composable SearchView wherever is needed

SearchView(state = textState, placeHolder = "")

val searchedText = textState.value.text
```

LazyColumn showing main list and if something entered in searchedText,
the list updates only with the searched items.

*Changed from itemsIndexed to items with key as item.id because after the list was updated according to the search, the index was reset so couldn't control my items in the same way.

```
LazyColumn() {

             items(items = inventoryList.filter {
             it.itemNumber.contains(searchedText, ignoreCase = true) ||
             it.itemDescription.contains(searchedText, ignoreCase = true)
    }, key = {it.id}) { item ->

                                    MainScreenItemRow(
                                        itemNumber = item.itemNumber,
                                        itemDescription = item.itemDescription,
                                     
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: is this a good solution ? For me it is but i don't know what is the difference between this and directly search into Room

Comment: I guess for such a simple implementation its preferred to just use the filter function, instead of starting to query the database each letter but I might be wrong. Also gonna clean the code since its too much.

Comment: Hard to grasp but once you get the idea this is a good solution!