# Add Filters to a Room Query after Runtime in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, android-livedata, composable

I have a Room query that I'm running when my app starts.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable")
fun get(): LiveData<List<MyItem?>?>
```

After the query runs, my user will select several filters which should be applied to the `tags` column of `myTable`.

I've got another query using `String`.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE tags LIKE '%' || :filters || '%'")
fun getFilteredByString(filters: Strings): LiveData<List<MyItem?>?>
```

I've also got a query using `Lists`.

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE tags IN (:filters)")
fun getFilteredByList(filters: List<Strings>): LiveData<List<MyItem?>?>
```

This is how I've set up my ViewModel:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(private val application: Application) : ViewModel() {
...
    private val database: MyDatabase = MyDatabase.getDatabase(application)
    private val myDao: MyDao = database.myDao()
    val results = myDao.get()
    val filters = MutableLiveData<List<String>?>()
...
}
```

***How do I switch the value in `results` to be one of the other two queries?***

I've tried several solutions unsuccessfully (e.g. [`switchMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769812/best-practice-runtime-filters-with-room-and-livedata), `@Transaction`, `MediationLiveData`). The solution should be that `results` is a static variable that is somehow transformed to another query in the `ViewModel` rather than in the `@Composable` for the UI.

I looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60559869/how-can-i-turn-a-list-of-strings-into-like-clauses-in-a-room-query), but it seems to involve going outside of the `Room` library's built-in capabilities, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Based on your answer, it sounds like your question is a duplicate of, "[How to implement a Room LiveData filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634643/how-to-implement-a-room-livedata-filter)"

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions:

1. [Removing `LiveData` from my DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634643/how-to-implement-a-room-livedata-filter).
2. Using [filtering within my LazyColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626861/jetpack-compose-how-to-search-and-display-specific-data-from-room-in-lazycolum), so I didn't even have to update my query (way faster computationally).

BONUS: Sorting is also possible on LiveData using [`Comparator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915584/sorting-list-items-in-lazycolumn-android-jetpack-compose).